# Передача значения переменно из Одного View в другой View SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui

у меня есть два View
LoginView и ProfileView

В LoginView имеется ряд значений:

```
@State private var email: String = "Email"
@State private var password: String = "Password"
@State private var showToggleSignup: Bool = false
@State private var showToggleLogin: Bool = true
@State private var showToggleReset: Bool = false
@State private var showProfileView: Bool = false
```

Эти значения изменяются по нажатию на различные кнопки в самом LoginView на пример путем:

```
Button {
     showToggleLogin.toggle()
     showToggleReset.toggle()
} label: {
     GradientButton(text: "forgot pass?")
         .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .leading)
         .opacity(showToggleLogin ? 0 : 1)
 }
```

Каким образом, находясь в ProfileView можно изменить эти значения для LoginView?

Очень буду признателен за помощь!
Может я чего то не понимаю, но я лишь только учусь!

Answer (score 0):

Начните использовать MVVM, ну или если быстро решить ваш вопрос, то @Appstorage